# how to resolve all references for a JSON schema in java

Tags: java, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I have a JSON schema , which has field like

1. $schema
2. $id
3. $ref
4. $merge

ex

```
{
  **"$schema"**: "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  **"$id"**: "./field_name_1.json",
  "field_name_title": "some-title",
  "field_name_2": "some value",
  "field_name_3": {
    "field_name_4": {
      "field_name_5": "some value",
      "field_name_6": "some value",
      "field_name_7": {
        "field_name_8": {
          "field_name_9": "some value",
          **"$ref"**: "/json_file_1.json"
        },
        "field_name_": {
          **"$ref"**: "/json_file_2.json"
        }
      },
      "field_name_10": false
    }
  },
  "field_name_11": "some value",
  "field_name_12": "some value",
  "field_name_13": {
    "field_name_14": {
      **"$ref"**: "/json_file_3.json"
    },
    "session_data": {
      **"$ref"**: "/json_file_4.json"
    },
    "event_payload": {
      **"$ref"**: "#/field_name_3/field_name_4"
    }
  },
  "field_name_15": false
}
```

how to resolve all references in the schema , and make a complete JSON.

Main goal is to map the resolved schema in to an entity and perform crud operation for schemas

Comment: Is it one time task or you need to do it on periodic basis?

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov Although i need it regularly , but what is the help for one time task ?

Comment: if it's one time task, you may use tools such as Notepad++ to do the replacement; if it's regular requirement, you may write some automation on java or python

Comment: @AlexanderMakarov : oh that , no , It has be done in the program , not a one time task

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to approach this task, i.e. implement as simple automation to replace tokens on your behalf that will perform following steps:

1. Create a map (Map, HashMap) that will have token - value pairs
2. Read json via json library; that's an example how to do it - https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json
3. Iterate through json and replace a token via replace method of java string.

Another approach is to do a replacement via external tools such as gradle that has a dedicated plugin for that. There are a bunch of plugins that can do that in gradle repository - https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=token+replacement, for example this one https://github.com/HexoMod-tools/gradle.replace.token.preprocessor.plugin

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [java-json-tools](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-core), project.

The `com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.RefResolver` class seems to have the functionality.
Refer: [javadoc](https://java-json-tools.github.io/json-schema-core/1.2.x/com/github/fge/jsonschema/core/load/RefResolver.html)

I have not tried it yet, so cannot add more information.